# Missing default edit form in SharePoint designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a list. I opened the site that contains it using SharePoint designer and then I selected Lists and Libraries on the left and then selected the list on the right. I could see that we have 2 forms for edit, the default edit.aspx and one additional form. I tried to do some changes and suddenly the default edit form disappeared from the list of forms. If I try to edit any list item in the browser, the edit page opens but empty. If I try to add a new form using the SharePoint designer with the name "edit", it gives me an error that a page with the same name already exists. I need to get the page back and undo any changes. I'm new to sharepoint so I would really appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The full page i.e. edit.aspx has been disappeared? or the page remains but the html inside it has been disappeared?

Comment: At the beginning, the page itself disappeared from the list of forms but I had the page with its html opened. Then I closed SharePoint designer and opened it again so I lost access to the form and it still doesn't appear in the list of forms. I dont think the html content is lost I think it's just something that I deleted by mistake that causes rhe page to load empty